# Do Gee collections (libgee) count references to stored data? (Gee and its memory management.)

Tags: vala

```
class ABC
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
}

Gee.HashMap<int, ABC> p;

void fn()
{
    p = new Gee.HashMap<int, ABC>();

    var x = new ABC();

    x.a = 3123;
    x.b = 1231;
    x.c = 5154;

    p.set(1, x);
}
```

Would this code work? Or my hash collection loses its data after the end of x visibility scope, i. e. when fn() returns?

Should I replace reference x by pointer to prevent this?

Should I explicitly delete this pointer after the p.unset(1) method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works. `x` is kept alive inside `p`. The Gee containers use reference counting.

The `p` object is never freed though, because it's a global variable. If you move it to a more local scope (say inside a main function) its data would be freed:

```
class ABC
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
}

Gee.HashMap<int, ABC> fn()
{
    var p = new Gee.HashMap<int, ABC>();

    var x = new ABC();

    x.a = 3123;
    x.b = 1231;
    x.c = 5154;

    p.set(1, x);
    return p;
}

void main() {
    Gee.HashMap<int, ABC> p = fn();
    stdout.printf("%d\n", p[1].a);
    // p and x are both freed here, because their ref count reaches 0
}
```

There is usually no need to `unset`, unless you want to manually remove the value from the HashMap.